# A few datasets: IP4/6, MAC, Cell ID

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for all or either of these datasets:

- MAC addresses with some additional info such as geo, may be something else
- all IP4 **and** **IP6** addresses with some additional info such as geo, may be something else
- WiFi addresses or names of spots with probably MAC addresses and some additional info such as geo or frequency, may be something else
- cell IDs with some additional info such as geo, may be something else

Either of these datasets can be splitted into small ones from different providers and I don't mind assemblying it myself. Preferably a dataset, not an API webservice, although if there's no other option....

Your suggestions?